# thickbox not load the embed tag content

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I need some advice about thickbox, please!
I've just follow the example in thickbox inline but I couldn't load the content of the div in my page as I wanna. My html code and jquery code like that. Any suggestion for my problem?

```
 $(".artist").hover(function(){
        var artistname = $(this).attr("title");
        var artist = "<embed hspace=\"5\" vspace=\"5\" ";
        artist += "src=\"http://abc.vn/res/music/passion/MP3_Player.swf\"";
        artist += "menu=\"false\" quality=\"high\" width=\"330\" height=\"338\"";
        artist += "name=\"index\" allowScriptAccess=\"never\" type=\"";
        artist += "application/x-shockwave-flash\" pluginspage=\"http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer\"";
        artist +=   "flashvars=\"&amp;config=http://abc.vn/res/music/passion/MP3_Config.xml&amp;";
        artist += "file=http://abc.vn/listsong.hightway?artist=" +artistname+ "\"";
        artist += "wmode=\"transparent\" border=\"0\"></embed>";

        $("#tooltip_artist").replaceWith(artist);
        $("#tooltip_artist").css({display:"none"});
    },function(){});

<a class="artist" title="singer's name" rel="#TB_inline&inlineId=tooltip_artist" href="/singer's name">singer's name</a>
```

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Thank Franz very much! I'm change replaceWith by html() as you said. Now I have two question and I can not answer this so I hope you will help me again! The first I using qtip or thickbox or something like those plugin but my problem is I wanna get the content to display from the div inside the page that contain the qtip or thickbox not like their example get dynamic content from html file. I waste three hours and really hopeless, can you give me some suggest?
The second is the embed tag always display after thickbox appearenced and I couldn't fixed it too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's not wise to use replaceWith here, because after the first hovering, the $('tooltip_artist') node will be replaced with your swf --> subsequent hoverings won't work. Its better to insert the embed code into the $('tooltip_artist') by using the .html() method.

then I'd use double/single quotes for the html snippet, so that you don't have to escape the attribute quotes all the time

```
var artist = '<embed hspace="5" vspace="5">';
```

Finally, are you sure you want to use .hover here? Obviously your intention is to play the music of an artist while the user is hovering over his name.

But in this case your approach is wrong. You'd better embed a scriptable mp3 player somewhere on the page and trigger its play method when the user is hovering over a track name. This gives a much better performace compared to always reinstantiating a swf Movie on .hover There is the nice jPlayer plugin for jQuery (completely styleable by CSS), you should have a look at that.